# Including DT::datatable in html vignette (Rmarkdown) produces output '<!–html_preserve–>'

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, r-package, dt

I've been trying to include the output of `datatable()` in a html vignette (you can check the source code [here](https://github.com/gvegayon/twitterreport/blob/master/vignettes/report_example.Rmd)). The problem is that, after I build and install the package, instead of showing the graphs the vignette shows this html tag that I don't get `<!–html_preserve–>` (just like [this example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggvis/vignettes/ggvis-basics.html))

Please note that the vignette is using `plot` methods that are wrappers of `datatable`. Methods' source code is [here](https://github.com/gvegayon/twitterreport/blob/master/R/methods.R).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Chances are you were using R Markdown v1: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/f89f76645027fe079de69793272f1382c2cdbb3e/R/utils-vignettes.R#L8-L24

Comment: That's right, I'm sorry, but I forgot to mention that I'm using Ubuntu and my own makefile to build the package. After installing `pandoc` and `pandoc-citeproc` (as show in here https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md) everything work fine.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Yihui maybe I am a maniac, but I'm trying to generate a .Rmd with datatable() on heroku, and there's a ton of extra overhead to get pandoc up -- is there any way to preserve `datatable()` without rendering with pandoc?